# Efficient way to find how many neighbouring elements with a specific value there are around a particular element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a 2D int array called myArray that is for example 3x3 size and its elements can only have either 1 or 0 for values, what would be an efficient way to calculate how many 1s there are around a particular element? E.g:

```
[0][0][0]
[0][1][0]
[1][1][1]
```

The element myArray[0][0] would have neighbourCount of 1 while myArray[0][1] would have a neighbourCount of 3.

This is my current brute force code. myArray = currentGeneration

```
public int neighbours(int x, int y)  { //x and y are 0 index based coordinates, they are swapped inside to corespond with actual x and y coordinates
        int neighbourCounter = 0;
        if(x == 0 && y == 0) {
            if(currentGeneration[y+1][x] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
            if(currentGeneration[y][x+1] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
            if(currentGeneration[y+1][x+1] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
        } else if(x == 0 && y == currentGeneration.length - 1) {
                            if(currentGeneration[y-1][x] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
                            if(currentGeneration[y][x+1] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
                            if(currentGeneration[y-1][x+1] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
        } else if(x == currentGeneration[0].length - 1 && y == currentGeneration.length - 1) {
                            if(currentGeneration[y-1][x] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
                            if(currentGeneration[y][x-1] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
                            if(currentGeneration[y-1][x-1] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
        } else if( y == 0 && x == currentGeneration[0].length - 1) {
                            if(currentGeneration[y][x-1] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
                            if(currentGeneration[y+1][x] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
                            if(currentGeneration[y+1][x-1] == 1) {
                                    neighbourCounter++;
                            }
        } else if(y == 0) {
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y][x+i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
            if(currentGeneration[y+1][x] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y+1][x+i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
        } else if(x == 0) {
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
            if(currentGeneration[y][x+1] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x+1] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
        } else if(y == currentGeneration.length - 1) {
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y][x+i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
            if(currentGeneration[y-1][x] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y-1][x+i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
        } else if(x == currentGeneration[0].length - 1) {
            for(int i = -1; i <= 2; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
            if(currentGeneration[y][x-1] == 1) {
                neighbourCounter++;
            }
            for(int i = -1; i <= 2; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x-1] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
                if(currentGeneration[y][x+i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x+i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
                if(currentGeneration[y+i][x-i] == 1) {
                    neighbourCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbourCounter;
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework??

Comment: What have you tried so far. If you post some code we can guide you as to whether you have done it correctly or if there is a better way.

Comment: No, I'm just wondering if there would be an efficient method to do this. My current method involves pretty much brute forcing it by checking where the particular "center" element is (one of the corners, one of the edges or the middle) and then checking possible neighbours without going out of the array bounds.

Comment: Is the text at the end of '*This is my current brute force code.* ***myArray = currentGeneration***' supposed to be there, or should it be part of the existing code?

Comment: That is just going from the example: myArray in my short example is the currentGeneration array in my code.

Comment: And just to be more precise: "This is my current brute force code. myArray = currentGeneration" is not part of the code

Comment: Google "Nearest Neighbor Search".  And just so you know, "brute force" is not always bad.

Comment: Or "How to make a Minesweeper game in Java" http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/minesweeper/

Comment: BTW, you have to define if wrapping around is allowed (boundaries). Depending on that rule, you can come up with different answer for your boundary cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that:

```
public static int findNeighbors(int x, int y, int[][] a) {
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = (y>0 ? y-1 : 0); i <= (y<a.length-1 ? y+1 : a.length-1); ++i )
        for ( int j = (x>0 ? x-1 : 0); j <= (x<a[0].length-1 ? x+1 : a[0].length-1); ++j )
            sum += a[i][j];
    sum -= a[y][x];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please note the edit in the 6th line: `sum -= a[y][x];` instead of `sum -= a[x][y];` Blame the order of Cartesian coordinates being different from the order of array indices :)